# What are those segments? CAD or language tips, please

Tags: postscript, cad

Inherited files with body content said to be from some unknown CAD system. To me it looks a bit like postscript. I would appreciate any tips and points wrt language description and how I could reconstruct curves/segments.

```
8
2
T06
43.220
0 -85.5 0
1

newpath 0.000 0.000
arcto 41.943 15.266
           64.260 53.921
lineto 76.669 124.293
closepath

newpath 0.000 -0.500
arcto 42.264 14.883
           64.752 53.834
lineto 77.000 123.293
closepath
```

Comment: Its not 'standard' PostScript syntax, but since PostScript is a programming language it could be a valid fragment of a larger program. Can't tell without seeing more.

Comment: @KenS ok, added header info, and that's it, that is a whole single file. I have few tens of them, structurally the same, of course some difference in data/numbers.

Comment: Not PostScript then, unless there's some more somewhere that stitches these fragments together. T06 isn't a standard PostScript operator, newpath doesn't take any arguments and it *looks* like the arguments in that code are **after** the operators whereas in PostScript (being a stack-based language) they precede the operators.

Comment: @KenS This is why I've added postscript tag - it looks like PS with arguments and operators order inverted. It is produced by some code system, but which one, that's the question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are only a few tens of them, you could write a program to roughly convert them into Postscript to at least see what you might have:

```
newpath
0.000 0.000 moveto
41.943 15.266 64.260 53.921 1 arcto
76.669 124.293 lineto
closepath

stroke

newpath
0.000 -0.500 moveto
42.264 14.883 64.752 53.834 1 arcto
77.000 123.293 lineto
closepath

stroke

showpage
```

The example file you provided seems to draw the same shape twice, with only slight variation -- I assume from the minimal drawing commands that all the files collectively add up to one (interesting) whole:

[image]